# Using Package control with an offline repo

Tags: sublimetext3

What is the workflow to use `package control` for sublime in an offline environment? Is it possible to setup your own repository that can be used to list and download packages available in your dedicated repo?.

I know that you can add a git path to a package, but I was thinking of a more seamless integration, like listing packages that are available in an offline repo.

Comment: Do you mean literally offline (i.e. no network connectivity at all to anything) or offline as in you can only connect to an intranet or local servers without having to talk to the internet at large (like inside a corporate environment)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, we can kind of maintain an offline repository by downloading stuff in a location but there is no way to get online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to explain how to set up an offline site such as the one you want, lets first cover the sequence of events that (logically) happens when you tell `Package Control` that you want to install a package by selecting `Package Control: Install Package` in the command palette:

1. Each package `channel` listed in the `channels` setting of the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file is contacted and the contents downloaded to obtain a list of package `repositories`
2. Each `repository` that this returns is downloaded to come up with the complete list of packages available in that repository.
3. The list of repositories set in the `repositories` key of the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file is similarly downloaded.
4. The contents of all of the different package repositories that these requests return are combined together into one list and presented to you for you to select the package to install.
5. The specifics of the package selected are used in order to download and install the package as appropriate.

`Package Control` comes with the `channels` setting set to a list that contains a single channel entry, which represents the contents of the default package control channel.

```json
"channels":
[
    "https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json"
],
```

In order to set up a offline package repository, you need to create your own custom `channel` and `repository` files and host them on a web server that will be accessible to everyone that needs to access the private repository, along with all of the packages that you're making available.

---

**Important:** It is ***mandatory*** that the web server serve the files via *https* or `Package Control` will refuse to load them for security reasons.

---

The [Package Control docs](https://packagecontrol.io/docs) have a page that talks a little bit about [channels and repositories](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/channels_and_repositories), including an [example channel](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbond/package_control/master/example-channel.json) file and an [example repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbond/package_control/master/example-repository.json) file to show you the structure and the available keys. As you proceed, you should refer to the sample files to see what is available.

Both the `channel` and `repository` files that you need to create are in JSON format and will provide all of the details for the packages that are available, which includes the versions of said packages, where they are available, version requirements, and so on.

It should also be mentioned that the bulk of all packages in the default Package Control channel are stored in GitHub or BitBucket repositories, and at installation time Package Control will download the latest release from those sites for installation.

In order to know when packages are updated, [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/) (where the default channel is hosted) has a crawler that visits the repository page for all of the packages that it contains on an hourly(ish) basis to detect new versions of packages.

In creating a private repository such as the one you want to create, you presumably have no access to GitHub or BitBucket, and so the onus will be on you to provide the appropriate `sublime-package` files for the packages in your channel as well as keeping abreast of new versions of packages and updating things as appropriate.

As an example, here is a minimal `channel` file that we will assume is available over the network at the URL `https://example.com/channel.json`.

```json
{
    "schema_version": "3.0.0",

    "repositories": [
        "https://example.com/packages.json"
    ]
}
```

In order to get Package Control to use this channel, you need to modify the `channels` setting in `Package Control.sublime-settings`, removing the default channel (which you presumably will be unable to access) and replacing it with your own channel URL instead. This is a list, allowing you to create as many channels as you need.

```json
"channels":
[
    "https://example.com/channel.json"
],
```

This step is important; without at least one channel in the list, Package Control will not install anything and will pop up a warning dialog telling you that there are no packages for installation.

When Package Control downloads the channel, it will then try to grab the `repository` that it contains, in order to determine the packages that are currently available and their versions.

As noted above, the channel file is going to look for the file at the URL `https://example.com/packages.json`, which might look like this:

```json
{
    "schema_version": "3.0.0",

    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "PackageTheFirst",
            "description": "A package to do some things",
            "homepage": "https://somewebpage.com/",
            "author": "developer name",
            "releases": [
                {
                    "version": "1.0.0",
                    "url": "https://example.com/sublime3/PackageTheFirst.sublime-package",
                    "date": "2017-01-25 11:33:25",
                    "sublime_text": ">=3126",
                    "platforms": ["*"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "OtherPackage",
            "description": "A package for other things",
            "homepage": "https://someotherwebpage.com/",
            "author": "another author",
            "releases": [
                {
                    "version": "1.0.3",
                    "url": "https://example.com/sublime3/CommentGlory.sublime-package",
                    "date": "2018-04-11 16:32:27",
                    "sublime_text": ">=3176",
                    "platforms": ["windows"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is listing a package named `PackageTheFirst` that's at version `1.0.0`, requires Sublime Text build 3126 or higher, and can be found at the URL `https://example.com/sublime3/PackageTheFirst.sublime-package`. There is also another package by the name `OtherPackage`, which is a Windows-only package and requires Sublime build 3176 or higher to install.

With these files in place and your configuration altered as appropriate, Package Control will list these packages for installation by users. If you update the versions in the repository file (and create an appropriate new `sublime-package` file), Package Control will notice and update the packages the same way that it normally would.

What this doesn't explain is where you would get the files and related channel entries for the packages that you want to reference in your custom channel.

If you're making third party packages from the default channel available, you can glean some of the information you need from the default channel entries. Note however that most channel entries include a link to the GitHub or BitBucket repository the package is stored in and most of the metadata for the package (author, version, etc) is gathered from there, so you will need to manually enter that information.

In the case where you're making your own custom packages available, it should be easier to determine the information that goes in the channel entry.

As a final note, depending on the number of repositories and packages that you're setting up, the channel file allows you to optimize it by including a cached copy of all of the packages stored in the referenced repositories, which allows Package Control to get the full list of packages and their information with only a single request.

There is more information on that in the sample channel file linked above.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive description, it is very helpful and seems indeed  more doable than I thought. We actually have access to internal git repos, hosted on our private network. I could fork the Github repo's for those packages and serve it from there, without the need of hosting the packages.